# isinstance(list, object) and issubclass(list, object) both returns True

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn about special attributes of classes. Usually, I use the `dir()` method to get the attributes and methods of a class. However, the attribute `__mro__` doesn't seem to appear in the results of `dir()` for any classes.

By definition, `dir()` recursively gets all the attributes and methods all the way up the chain of inheritance, from the passed-in class to the base class, `object`. Based on this definition, I assumed that the attribute `__mro__` is not actually an attribute of any classes along the aforementioned inheritance chain.

Later, I stumbled upon the class `type` and found that it contained the `mro` method in its method descriptions `help(type)`. I thought, a class must inherit from `type` to use this method. So I did a test with a new style class called `Apple`:

- `isinstance(Apple, type)` returns `True`
- `issubclass(Apple, type)` returns `False`
- even `isinstance(object, type)` returns `True`

Strangely, `Apple` does not inherit from `type`; instead, it is an instance of it. This confuses me a lot: I do not know where does the `__mro__` come from now.

Comment: Closely related: [What are metaclasses in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/100003)

Comment: Can you please ask a specific question? This has been you rambling about things that confuse you, but what exactly is the question you want answered?